# can i get real time status updates using the Graph Real Time API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, real-time

I have an app that currently that i have to cron to run that gets a bunch of user status updates using https://graph.facebook.com/the-selected-user/statuses?access_token
and this works fine. I run a cron once an hour. I would like to use the Real-time Updates, but not sure how to do that. I have the example subscription working, but can not make the connection on how to subscribe to what to get the users status updates
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have subscriptions working (the hard part), just add a subscription for topic: user and field: feed.

From the API documentation:

> way you subscribe to a user's feed - the subscription topic should be
>   'user' and the subscription field should be 'feed'